# Is it possible to have a footnote in rotated material?

Tags: footnotes, rotating

I'd like to have a footnote in a rotated material but each solution I tried (with `\rotatebox` from `graphicx` package, `rotate` environment from `isorot` or `rotating` packages, etc.) fails: the footnote mark is as expected but the footnote text (that I'd like not rotated and located, as usual, at the bottom of the page) isn't displayed.

The following MWE shows the trouble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{rotate}{90}
  Foo\footnote{Bar.}.
\end{rotate}
\end{document}
```

I guess this is related to an underlying box for the rotated material. But, anyway, is it possible to have a footnote in rotated material?

Comment: Yes, for example, if you rotate a table with footnotes and put it inside a minipage, the alphabetic table notes will be rotated as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rotation isn't really relevant the trouble is it's a box, you would see the same problem with `\mbox{...\footnote{}}` use

```
\rotatebox{}{...\footnotemark}\footnotetext{the text of the footnote}
```

(You can also use `rotate` environment but that's just a wrapper around `\rotatebox` for compatibility with the LaTeX2.09 `rotating` package.)

If you are rotating the whole page, you can use `lscape` package `landscape` environment which does allow footnotes to be used directly.